# developing a metrics for prioritizing attack patterns based on a database for attack patterns(CAPEC)

Tags: attacks, threat-modeling

I have data on attack patterns which has various attributes like severity of attack, attackers skill, attack likelihood all in the form of linguistic values like high, medium and low. I want to develop a metrics for prioritizing these attack patterns based on the above attributes. Should I convert low to 1 medium to 2 and high to 3 or use some other normalization technique.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about security itself. It essentially asks what a useful mapping (this is not normalization as claimed) of some discrete feature values into integers  would be so that one gets a metric which can be used for sorting/prioritizing. That these features are in the context of security is actually irrelevant for the question. stats.stackexchange.com might be a more appropriate site for such questions.